# Python error: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

I'm trying to run a SQL query on Python using cx_Oracle, and keep getting an error message, the complete error looks like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Z:\fex\petrolpanel\PPL.PY", line 45, in '<'module'>'
>
> curs.execute(sql)
>
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

At first I thought it was because I was parsing some variables into the query, but I removed those, then I thought it was because the original had some built in calculations on it, so I removed that too. It is still not working.

Here's the relevant portion of the script:

```
sql = """"
SELECT PERIOD_YEAR, PERIOD_WEEK, PURCHASE_NUMBER, 
VALIDATION_FIELD, ORIGINAL_VAL_FIELD, SHOP_CODE, 
QUANTITY, TOTAL_PRICE
FROM OPS$OM1.ET0800
WHERE DELETE_FLAG = 'N' AND LATE_FLAG = 'E' AND ERROR_FLAG <> 'F' 
AND VALIDATION_FIELD < 100 AND PERIOD_YEAR = 2016 AND PERIOD_WEEK BETWEEN 41 AND 44
"""

# Execute SQL
curs.execute(sql)

rows = curs.fetchall()
```

Every thing before this works fine, and nothing runs after this. Any ideas what could be wrong? When I look at the error itself on Google I get:

> You tried to reference a table, cluster, view, index, synonym, tablespace, or username with a value that was longer than 30 characters.

But nothing on that query is over 30 characters, I think the longest field is 18 characters and the table name itself is only 6 characters long. I can run this query on Oracle Developer without any problems either.

Help, please.

Comment: `sql = """"` You have 4 sets of double quotes there, not 3.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem, you are a star!

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me recently. Instead of opening your character string with three quotes, you have put four. Result: Oracle tries to interpret the whole request as an identifier.

Best regards